# How to hide an element behind a smaller one?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I am creating an AutoComplete component but I am having a problem because I want the suggestions to animate into existence by sliding down. I am using the `transform: translateY` CSS in order to have it be performant on mobile.

So basically what I need to have happen is for the suggestions to hide behind the textbox, and to slide down and appear when the user begins typing. This only slightly works because the suggestions list is taller than the textbox. As a result, it can't fully hide behind textbox as it clips out of the top.

I have created a working example that demonstrates the problem [at this link](https://jsfiddle.net/geyv9d81/3/), and also have reproduced the code here (try typing into the textbox):

```js
document.querySelector(".autocomplete").oninput = e => {
  let value = e.target.value;

  if (value.length > 0) {
    document.querySelector(".suggestions").classList.add("open");
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".suggestions").classList.remove("open");
  }
}
```

```css
.autocomplete {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.suggestions {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 125px;
  width: 500px;
  transform: translateY(-30px);
  transition: .25s;
  background-color: #eef;
}

.open {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<p>Some text and a paragraph preceding the autocomplete</p>
<div>
  <input class="autocomplete" />
  <div class="suggestions">apple, banana, carrot, dog</div>
</div>
```

I would like to make the `transform: translateY(-30px);` instead to be `transform: translateY(-130px);`, but then it clips before the textbox. I want it to hide behind the textbox instead. Also, I don't think I can use `scale` here because I don't want it to look bad and distorted while animating in.

Depending on the state of the application, I may have different elements preceding this, so while a bandage solution of "put something before it" might work, it seems sloppy and not very scalable.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a `placeholder="type here"` for your input and then in your css sheet add

```
input:not(:placeholder-shown)+div {
  display: block;
}

.autocomplete {
 display: none;
}
```

working pen:
https://codepen.io/yael-screenovate/pen/KKVxrrj

Comment: I'm confused. This doesn't seem to do anything? It still clips when sliding down, and has now even gotten rid of the sliding up animation. Am i missing something?